# How to query integers in fields in Cloud Firestore using Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to figure out how to query numbers in cloud firestore. Here is my code:

```
final result = await Firestore.instance.collection('Social_Posts').where(30, isGreaterThan: "views").getDocuments();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: 'package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_query.dart': Failed assertion: line 119 pos 12: 'field is String || field is FieldPath': Supported [field] types are [String] and [FieldPath].
```

Looks like cloud firestore queries only accept strings.
If that is the case, then how can I query numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops its simple.

Just do the following:

```
final result = await Firestore.instance.collection('Social_Posts').where("views", isGreaterThan: 30).getDocuments();
```

Comment: Yeah, this is correct. The reason is you enclosed your (views) variable in quotes, which means it references the string "views" rather than the value of the variable (views)